# Time series decomposition gives unexpected results

Tags: time-series

Made up data:

```
TIME    VALUE
2016-01 5
2016-02 10
2016-03 15
2016-04 20
2016-05 25
2016-06 30
2016-07 25
2016-08 20
2016-09 15
2016-10 10
2016-11 5
2016-12 0
....
2018-01 7
2018-02 12
2018-03 17
2018-04 22
2018-05 27
2018-06 32
2018-07 27
2018-08 22
2018-09 17
2018-10 12
2018-11 7
2018-12 2
```

Logic Used: Jan = 5, Increase by 5 till June, Decrease by 5 after that. Next year, add 1 to each value.

Run Additive time series decomposition

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]
result = seasonal_decompose(df, model='addictive',freq = 12)
result.plot()
plt.show()
```

Results:
[image]

Maybe this is due to my limited statistical knowledge, but I was expecting that the trend component would simply be 0,1,2 and seasonal component would be 2016 values. However as can be seen from graph, the trend component starts from 15, which has been subtracted from seasonal component. Any guidance on this would be really helpful. Maybe I am completely wrong here and deploying wrong statistical method?

Comment: Why don't you post your data an I will try and help you further ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the trend component estimates a **changing mean**. Expecting the mean to be equal to the local minimum of the series is not reasonable. A back-of-the-envelope calculation for the varying mean would be a 12 months rolling average. And this seems to be (more or less) what the python code is doing.

Comment: To expand a bit, seasonal components average out to zero over the course of the "season" (year in this case) in question.  Given that, the trend term has to capture the level of the series as well as the change in the series.

Comment: Seasonal indeed has to average out to zero. The trend captures the level of the series as well as the change level in the series. A good question would be on frequencies/scales the trend leaves, and that depends on the nature of the series.